# scrapy.Reaquests() callback not work

Tags: python, scrapy

There are lots of questions about this though, but most of people encounter this problem because of the "dont_filter' argument. I passed this argument "dont_filter = True" but my custom parse generator still didn't work. Here is my code(the third parser "parse_spec" had never been called, "parse_models_follow_next_page" just work well when called by parse(), but it can't call itself when it need to turn to next page):

```
import scrapy
from gsmarena.items import PhoneItems

class VendorSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    custom_settings = {
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 1.5,
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.75.14 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.3 Safari/7046A194A',
        'COOKIES_ENABLED': False
    }

    name = "gsmarena_spec"

    allowed_domains = ["https://www.gsmarena.com/"]

    start_urls = [
        "https://www.gsmarena.com/makers.php3"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        # print("Existing settings: %s" % self.settings.attributes.items())
        length = len(response.xpath("//table//a").extract())
        for i in range(1, length):
            brand = response.xpath(
                '(//table//a)[{}]/text()'.format(i)).extract()[0]
            url = "https://www.gsmarena.com/" + \
                response.xpath("(//table//a)[{}]/@href".format(i)).extract()[0]
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_models_follow_next_page, meta={'brand': brand}, dont_filter=True)

    def parse_models_follow_next_page(self, response):
        brand = response.meta.get('brand')
        length = len(response.xpath(
            "//div[@class='makers']/self::div//a").extract())
        for i in range(1, length):
            url = "https://www.gsmarena.com/" + \
                response.xpath(
                    "(//div[@class='makers']/self::div//a)[{}]/@href".format(i)).extract()[0]
            model = response.xpath(
                "(//div[@class='makers']/self::div//a//span/text())[{}]".format(i)).extract()[0]
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_spec, meta={'brand': brand, 'model': model}, dont_filter=True)
        is_next_page = response.xpath(
            "//a[@class=\"pages-next\"]/@href").extract()

        if is_next_page:
            next_page = "https://www.gsmarena.com/" + is_next_page[0]
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse_models_follow_next_page, meta={'brand': brand}, dont_filter=True)



    def parse_spec(self, response):
        item = PhoneItems()
        item['model'] = response.meta.get('model')
        item['brand'] = response.meta.get('brand')
        for spec_name, spec in zip(response.xpath('//table//td[1]').extract(), response.xpath('//table//td[2]').extract()):
        item[spec_name] = spec
        yield item
```

and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: it works fine on my side: `{'model': '45 Titanium', '<td class="ttl"><a...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You scraper has few issues.

```
allowed_domains = ["https://www.gsmarena.com/"]
```

should be

```
allowed_domains = ["www.gsmarena.com"]
```

Next you don't have `errback_httpbin` method defined in your class

```
def errback_httpbin(self, response):
    pass
```

Below code

```
for spec_name, spec in zip(response.xpath('//table//td[1]').extract(), response.xpath('//table//td[2]').extract()):
```

should be

```
for spec_name, spec in zip(response.xpath('//table//td[1]/text()').extract(), response.xpath('//table//td[2]/text()').extract()):
```

This though still has some issues.

Also your code would take some time for the first yield, as the scheduler will pick url based on the order of urls coming in

Comment: I have defineded the errback_httpbin function and forgot to post here, sorry for that.  Thanks for your advices.

Comment: And you are right I just need more patient. I tried my script again and the third paser had been called decades of seconds later. It is my first time to use scrapy and I thought it would work in sequence. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes in the code and it scraps all the results expect the spec_name, that is not specified in an understanding way.

import scrapy

from lxml import html

from tutorial.items import PhoneItems

class VendorSpider(scrapy.Spider):

```
   custom_settings = {
    'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 1.5,
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) 
    AppleWebKit/537.75.14 (KHTML, '
                  'like Gecko) Version/7.0.3 Safari/7046A194A',
    'COOKIES_ENABLED': False
    }
    name = "gsmarena_spec"
    allowed_domains = ["https://www.gsmarena.com/"]
    start_urls = [
        "https://www.gsmarena.com/makers.php3"
    ]

   def parse(self, response):
        # print("Existing settings: %s" % 
        self.settings.attributes.items())
        length = len(response.xpath("//table//a").extract())
        for i in range(1, length):
            brand = response.xpath(
            '(//table//a)[{}]/text()'.format(i)).extract()[0]
            url = "https://www.gsmarena.com/" + \
            response.xpath("(//table//a)
                [{}]/@href".format(i)).extract()[0]
            yield scrapy.Request(url,
                callback=self.parse_models_follow_next_page,
                meta={'brand':brand},dont_filter=True)

   def parse_models_follow_next_page(self, response):
        brand = response.meta.get('brand')
        meta = response.meta
        doc = html.fromstring(response.body)
        single_obj = doc.xpath('.//div[@class="makers"]/ul//li')
        for obj in single_obj:
            url = self.allowed_domains[0]+obj.xpath('.//a/@href')[0]
            meta['brand'] = obj.xpath('.//a/@href')[0].split('_')[0]
            meta['model'] = obj.xpath('.//a/@href')[0]
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_spec, 
                meta=meta, dont_filter=True)
        is_next_page = response.xpath(
                       "//a[@class=\"pages-next\"]/@href").extract()
        if is_next_page:
            next_page = "https://www.gsmarena.com/" + is_next_page[0]
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page, 
            callback=self.parse_models_follow_next_page, 
            meta={'brand': brand},dont_filter=True)

    def parse_spec(self, response):
        item = PhoneItems()
        meta = response.meta
        item['model'] = meta['model']
        item['brand'] = meta['brand']

        #Need to specify details about spec_name
        # for spec_name, spec in 
        #zip(response.xpath('//table//td[1]').extract(),
        #  response.xpath('//table//td[2]').extract()):
        #     item[spec_name] = spec
        yield item
```

Comment: Your code works great, thanks for your hard working. The spec_name is for record some spec's of smartphone such as cpu, screen size etc.